# FTP Plugin for Atom Editor

Tags: ftp, plugins, sftp, atom-editor

Is there a plugin or functionality to enable FTP and SFTP (optional) on [Atom Editor](https://atom.io/)?

It'd be useful if I can `work` directly on the remote server and saving the file it'll be saved directly on the (s)FTP server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find [FTP plugins for Atom](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=ftp) in the Packages section of their website. You should find one or two that do everything you need it to.